Trouble with expo-updates
I have configured my app with expo-updates and configure all versions in app.config.ts and eas.json as stipulated in expo docs. but every time i make build with eas i encountered two situations (issues)

When build with eas I get this issue

Runtime version mismatch:

Runtime version calculated on local machine: 1.0.7

Runtime version calculated on EAS: *****

This may be due to one or more factors:

Differing result of conditional app config (app.config.js) evaluation for runtime version resolution.

Differing fingerprint when using fingerprint runtime version policy. If applicable, see fingerprint diff below.

This would cause any updates published on the local machine to not be compatible with this build. Runtime version calculated on local machine not equal to runtime version calculated during build.

After read carefully expo docs, i was able to conclude that when using expo-updates, every time i make a new build, I must increment the runtimeVersion and the runtimeVersion should match with expo.version for compatibility of js bundle and native code.



The second situation i faced is every time I make a new build with new runtimeVersion and expo.version incremented, on testflight the build goes on the previous version instead to create a new version tab on app store connect --> testflight. I would expect a new version tab with its new build on testflight. Why this happens.



-- my entry point file contains the following function to check and fetch updates expo-updates
const checkAndFetchAppUpdates = async () => {
    try {
      const update = await Updates.checkForUpdateAsync();
      if (update.isAvailable) {
        await Updates.fetchUpdateAsync();
        await Updates.reloadAsync();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      const errorMessage =
        error.response && error.response.data
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message;
      reportError({
        error: error,
        errorInfos: `AICAFAU - ${errorMessage}`,
      });

      customAlert.alert({
        title: "Error when fetching updates",
        subTitle: `${errorMessage}`,
      });
    }
  };

--> My app.config.ts
export default ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => {
  // const isStaging = process.env.APP_VARIANT === "staging";
  //const env = getEnvVars();

  const appOwner = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_APP_OWNER;
  const appName = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_APP_NAME as string;
  const appScheme = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_APP_SCHEME;
  const appSlug = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_APP_SLUG as string;
  const appVersion = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_APP_VERSION;
  const projectId = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID;
  const appBundleIdentifier = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_APP_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER;
  const googleMapsApiKey = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY;

  const baseConfig: ExpoConfig = {
    ...config,
    name: appName,
    owner: appOwner,
    scheme: appScheme,
    version: appVersion,
    runtimeVersion: "1.0.7",
    // runtimeVersion: {
    //   policy: "appVersion", // Matches the runtimeVersion to the app's version field
    // },
    slug: appSlug,
    privacy: "public",
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: projectId,
      },
    },
    ios: {
      usesIcloudStorage: true,
      supportsTablet: true,
      bundleIdentifier: appBundleIdentifier,
      //  buildNumber: appVersion,
      infoPlist: {
        NSFaceIDUsageDescription: "This app uses Face ID for automatic login.",
        NSCameraUsageDescription:
          "This app uses the camera to scan user receipts in paper format.",
      },
      config: {
        googleMapsApiKey: googleMapsApiKey,
      },
    },

    android: {
      permissions: ["android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"],
      package: appBundleIdentifier,
      runtimeVersion: appVersion,
      // versionCode: 3, // You have to update this every time you make a new build
      adaptiveIcon: {
        foregroundImage: "./src/assets/images/app_icon.png",
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
      },
      config: {
        googleMaps: {
          apiKey: googleMapsApiKey,
        },
      },
    },

    updates: {
      enabled: true,
      url: `https://u.expo.dev/${projectId}`,      fallbackToCacheTimeout: 15000,
      checkAutomatically: "ON_LOAD",
    },
  };

  return baseConfig;
};

And in eas.json file, i set autoIncrement to true.
What I didn't undersatand? Please clarify me
